# How to get rid of dark spots?

Tags: cleaning

I have alot of dark spots on my face specially on cheeks. Which home remedy I used to get rid of it? And what should I add in my diet to remove these dark spots? Can anyone suggest me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mask which is very useful for dark spots.

Ingredients used :

1tsp Rice Flour

2 tsp Yogurt/ Curd

1 Tsp tomato juice .

mix all the ingredients well and apply on face for 15 minutes and wash your face with warm water.

The other method is apply potato juice on face it is very effective for dark spots.

There is no side effect of these remedies because they are natural ingredients.

Comment: If only all natural ingredients were harmless or free of side effects. Try a paste of mustard seeds and warm water, if you need a counter example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Yogurt mask for removing dark spots,take some yogurt and apply it on your face ,after 15 minutes when you see that mask is dry wash it with warm water.yogurt is the best remedy for removing dark spots.